# python speech-to-text using google api returning empty array?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to make a python script which takes a '.wav' file and returns the text.  So i did this:

```
import httplib
import json
import sys


def speech_to_text(audio):
    url = 'www.google.com'
    path = '/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&maxresults=1&pfilter=2&xjerr=1&lang=en-US&key=AIzaSyBdMw04YuFYZAqaUbOlp_85PZWXFTyoz10'
    # path = '/tag/?client=chromium&xjerr=1&lang=en-US&key=AIzaSyAovcASpSCspTHTRXAF5pSzIl4BrBILOSY'
    headers = {"Content-type": "audio/x-flac; rate=16000"}
    # params = {"": "1", "client": "chromium"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url)
    conn.request("POST", path, audio, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print (response)
    data = response.read()
    print (data)
    jsdata = json.loads(data)
    # return jsdata["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"]
    # return jsdata["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"]
    return jsdata
```

but everytime it returns this :

```
{"result":[]}
```

I am using python2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a wav file but your POST says it's a FLAC? (audio/x-flac)

You will want to convert the .WAV to .FLAC before requesting google to transcribe it.